# Host subdomain on a second DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system

I currently have a virtual machine from fast hosts, and I also use their domain hosting to.

On their name servers I have a zone file for my domain (lets say domain.co.uk), with A records for www, ftp etc. These A records point to my virtual server, where I am running IIS.

I have now also set up DNS on my virtual server, and created a subdomain (internal.domain.co.uk), and some A records (web.internal.domain.co.uk).

What do I need to do in my zonefile for domain.co.uk, to send requests for internal.domain.co.uk to my virtual server?

Thanks in advance

Mark

Comment: Dare I ask why you wouldn't just set up the subdomain on your primary DNS host?  It would seem easier/cleaner.

Comment: Because I can't install software on the fasthost dns server, but on my virtual server I can create a web service to update some a records with the dynamic IP of my home connection where me dev server is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a name server for the subdomain in your zone file for domain.co.uk

```
; sub-domain definitions
$ORIGIN internal.domain.co.uk.
; we define a name server for the sub-domain
@             IN      NS     ns3.internal.domain.co.uk.

; sub-domain address records for name server only - glue record
ns3           IN      A      10.10.0.24 ; 'glue' record
```

See http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/delegate.html for more details and advanced configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I could find to do this was to add another name server to my zone file, that points to my Virtual Server. The virtual server holds another copy of the domain, and the subdomain